# Как организовать взаимодействие с++ кода и с# формы?

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, c++-cli

Моей задачей было написание математической модели на С++, которая моделирует работу гидравлической системы, что я и сделал. Для удобства тестирования и демонстрации результатов я бы хотел реализовать GUI, допустим на C# winforms. На форме должно быть порядка 30 объектов, которые должны взаимодействовать с методами, связанными с атрибутами объектов в с++ коде. Математическая модель должна крутиться в отдельном потоке (backgroundworker?). Каким способом организовать взаимодействие с++ кода и с# формы в данном случае?

В сети много примеров, которые демонстрируют реализацию вызова методов с++ из с# формы, но обычно это методы абстрактных классов и выполняются они не в отдельном потоке. Потратил 2 недели на изучение вопроса, но очевидного и ясного для новичка в с# решения не нашел.

Comment: 1) Пишете класс-обертку  для вашей библиотеки 2) Работаете с оберткой как с обычным C# классом

Comment: Если пользовались Qt, то проще на нем сделать GUI. А вообще на c++ много GUI библиотек

Comment: 1) Запаковываете с++ функции в dll и вызываете функции из dll. 2) Есть старенький с++/cli, который компилируется в cli, как и c#. 3) Есть новенький c++/cx, в котором можно писать UI почти как и в с# (xaml) , но программы работают только на вин 10.

Comment: У меня не библиотека, а модель, т.е. библиотека, конфигурация модели, состоящая из объектов (которых может быть 10000) и решатель (итератор). При этом шаг итератора не более 5 миллисекунд, сейчас это вообще 1 миллисекунда. Расчет должен выполняться в реальном времени

Comment: И я не очень понимаю, ну напишу я обёртку для библиотеки, или запакую ее в dll, все равно в c# придется переносить конфигурацию модели и итератор.

Comment: Мне же надо по сути обмениваться между формой и матмоделью 30-50 сигналами (переменными) с шагом синхронизации 0,5-1 секунда. Возможны ли другие решения?